# Clone git repository in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I'm new to git, as I found to download files the path should end with .git extention. The sources I need are stored here https://dev.vaadin.com/git/. How can I take for example addons/calendar/calendar.git sources?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As seen [in this thread](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/1626368/exclusive), the proper url for cloning the [dev.vaadin.com/git addons/calendar](https://dev.vaadin.com/git/?p=addons/calendar/calendar.git;a=summary) repo was:

```
http://dev.vaadin.com/git/addons/calendar/calendar.git
```

But considering it was [moved to GitHub](https://dev.vaadin.com/), the Calendar is now part of the framework GitHub repo:

```
https://github.com/vaadin/framework
```

Add that in your URI field of the Git Clone dialog box

The old [dev.vaadin.com/git/?p=addons/calendar/calendar.git;a=tree](https://dev.vaadin.com/git/?p=addons/calendar/calendar.git;a=tree) content is visible in [vaadin/framework/compatibility-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/v7/ui/components/calendar](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/tree/master/compatibility-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/v7/ui/components/calendar).

Comment: Unfortunally, it doesn't work. The error box appears and log says:

Comment: !MESSAGE http://dev.vaadin.com/git/addons/calendar/calendar.git: 301 Moved Permanently
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: http://dev.vaadin.com/git/addons/calendar/calendar.git: 301 Moved Permanently
 at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:196)
 at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:99)

Comment: @Martin OK. I have edited my answer accordingly: the old content is now on GitHub under one big umbrella repository "framework".